# Unity Interception: How to pass parameter into ICallHandler implementation?

Tags: c#, unity-container, interception, unity-interception

Can I pass **message** parameter to ICallHandler implementation like this:

```
var logic = container.Resolve<IBussinessLogic>(message);
```

And use it like this:

```
IMethodReturn ICallHandler.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Format(
                "Begin {0} with param {1}",
                input.MethodBase.Name, 
                message // parameter I need to be passed
            )
        );

        var result = getNext.Invoke()(input, getNext);

        Console.WriteLine("End " + input.MethodBase.Name);
        return result;
    }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `message` you're passing to the `Resolve` method is actually the named instance name for Unity to construct. This value is used by Unity to select which implementation of `IBusinessLogic` to use; after construction of the implementing object it is lost.

This value is therefore only within Unity during the object's construction; your `ICallHandler` cannot access it as [you cannot intercept constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx).

Comment: I know this code do not work. I wrote this to describe my idea. All I need - to pass parameter from resolve-calling code to ICallHandler implementation.
Also I found that it is possible somehow to pass parameter to ICallHandler implementation constructor. But ICallHandler contructor calls only once per container (as I tested). But I need pass parameter avery time I call Resolve<>().

Comment: What is the nature of the `message`? Is it something you know at design-time?

Comment: In my example it is **string**. In my real world application it is **System.Web.Services.WebService**. My aspect trying to preform preparations with instance of **WebService** before real logic will be called.

Comment: I see. To be honest, this doesn't sound possible using interception. You could do it with a decorator instead?

Comment: Please feel free to email me if you'd like to discuss this in more depth :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that Steve Wilkes was right: "To be honest, this doesn't sound possible using interception."

http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/265679